# Why there is index in 2nd group array?

Tags: php, laravel

I am an array as like below

```
[
        {
            "id": 1,
            "game_id": 5,
            "user_id": 61,
            "played_level": 1,
            "group": "easy",
            "created_at": "2019-10-24 11:12:02",
            "updated_at": "2019-10-24 11:16:13"
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "game_id": 7,
            "user_id": 61,
            "played_level": 1,
            "group": "easy",
            "created_at": "2019-10-24 11:56:04",
            "updated_at": "2019-10-24 11:56:04"
        },
        {
            "id": 4,
            "game_id": 7,
            "user_id": 61,
            "played_level": 3,
            "group": "intermediate",
            "created_at": "2019-10-24 11:58:47",
            "updated_at": "2019-10-24 12:02:02"
        },
        {
            "id": 5,
            "game_id": 10,
            "user_id": 61,
            "played_level": 3,
            "group": "advance",
            "created_at": "2019-10-24 12:03:07",
            "updated_at": "2019-10-24 12:03:07"
        },
        {
            "id": 6,
            "game_id": 11,
            "user_id": 61,
            "played_level": 3,
            "group": "advance",
            "created_at": "2019-10-24 12:18:28",
            "updated_at": "2019-10-24 12:18:28"
        }
    ]
```

I would like to store into group wise array, as you can see foreach loop store values into group accordingly

```
foreach($todayTraining->toArray() as $training){

        if($todayTraining[$index]['group'] === 'easy'){
            $gameTraining['easy'][$index]['game_id'] = $todayTraining[$index]['game_id'];
            $gameTraining['easy'][$index]['played_level'] = $todayTraining[$index]['played_level'];
        }
        if($todayTraining[$index]['group'] === 'intermediate'){
            $gameTraining['intermediate'][$index]['game_id'] = $todayTraining[$index]['game_id'];
            $gameTraining['intermediate'][$index]['played_level'] = $todayTraining[$index]['played_level'];
        }
        if($todayTraining[$index]['group'] === 'advance'){
            $gameTraining['advance'][$index]['game_id'] = $todayTraining[$index]['game_id'];
            $gameTraining['advance'][$index]['played_level'] = $todayTraining[$index]['played_level'];
        }
        $index++;     
    }
```

In the result I am getting following array

```
"data": {
        "easy": [
            {
                "game_id": 5,
                "played_level": 1
            },
            {
                "game_id": 6,
                "played_level": 2
            },
            {
                "game_id": 7,
                "played_level": 1
            }
        ],
        "intermediate": {
            "3": {
                "game_id": 7,
                "played_level": 3
            }
        },
        "advance": {
            "4": {
                "game_id": 10,
                "played_level": 3
            },
            "5": {
                "game_id": 11,
                "played_level": 3
            }
        }
    }
```

You can see in `easy` group there is not indexes but in other two groups there is `indexes`. I am not sure why it is coming. Is there any idea that I can remove it. I would really appreciate. Thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

A normal, zero-based index does not need to be explicitly specified - but once you have an array start with a different index value, the indexes need to mentioned explicitly.

Because you are using `$index` here, which you are increasing in each loop iteration, you get a zero-based index in the first sub-array, but then when it comes to the 2nd and 3rd, it starts as 3 resp. 4 already.

You can either fix this by applying `array_values` to each of the sub-arrays after your are done gathering the data (that simply re-indexes an array to a zero-based, consecutive index) - or you don’t explicitly specify the index to begin with, but let PHP determine it. But then you will have to assign both values in one go, otherwise you would be creating *two* new elements for game id and played level each time.

So modify your code this way (accordingly for the other two cases):

```
if($todayTraining[$index]['group'] === 'easy'){
  $gameTraining['easy'][] = [
    'game_id' => $todayTraining[$index]['game_id'],
    'played_level' => $todayTraining[$index]['played_level']
  ];
}
```

---

Edit: Since you are doing basically the same thing in all three cases, you don’t even need to have three different branches here. The *only* thing that is different, is the index used on the first level, easy, intermediate, advanced.

But since you already *have* that value in variable, you can access it and assign your first level array key directly - then you don’t need any ifs any more, and the body of your loop simply becomes

```
$gameTraining[$todayTraining[$index]['group']][] = [
//             ^^^ index dynamically inserted here
  'game_id' => $todayTraining[$index]['game_id'],
  'played_level' => $todayTraining[$index]['played_level']
];
$index++;
```